# data and salt arguments required node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules, bcrypt

i am testing the authentication for my app and i got this error but could not solve it can you guys help me. Something is wrong with the bcrypt and salt etc but i could not figure out the reason.

I have add my package.json, Server and functions files. I had bcryptjs the old one in here first so i deleted and installed Bcrypt new one but still having a problem

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Here is the server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

require('dotenv').config();
app.use(express.json())
const dbConfig = require('./config/dbConfig');
const usersRoute = require("./routes/usersRoute");

app.use('/api/users', usersRoute);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}!`))
```

Here is my UserRoute

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
 
 
// register user account
 
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // check if user already exists
 
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "User already exists",
      });
    }
 
    // hash password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
   
    req.body.password = hashedPassword;
    const newUser = new User(req.body);
    await newUser.save();
    res.send({
      message: "User created successfully",
      data: null,
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({
      message: error.message,
      success: false,
    });
  }
});
 
// login user account
 
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // check if user exists
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "User does not exist",
      });
    }
 
    // check if password is correct
    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
      req.body.password,
      user.password
    );
    if (!validPassword) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "Invalid password",
      });
    }
 
    // check if user is verified
    if (!user.isVerified) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "User is not verified yet or has been suspended",
      });
    }
 
    // generate token
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, process.env.jwt_secret, {
      expiresIn: "1d",
    });
    res.send({
      message: "User logged in successfully",
      data: token,
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({
      message: error.message,
      success: false,
    });
  }
});
 
 
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Could you include the exact error and stack trace and point to the problematic line?

Comment: So, on the console or the terminal everything is fine nothing shows up but when we register it notifies the error message using the ant design message complement that salt and arguments required that’s why it’s confusing

Comment: Please provide the error in the body of the question, in the form of a proper stack trace as well as an indicator next to the problematic line.
e.g. `const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt); // < this line causes the error`